# What term means for something to be 'in place' in literature or screenwriting?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to recall a very specific word that..

- Is typically used in the context of film/tv/screen writing
- Describes something that the writer has put in their imaginary world (usually but not necessarily physical)
- Means that this something is 'in-place', 'sympathetic to the imaginary world', 'consistent'
- When used usually implies that this thing would otherwise be very out of place or noticeable, that the screen writer has done a good job of integrating it

Examples:

"The {} telephone-like device didn't break my suspension of disbelief, like it could have if done wrong."

"The X is very {}, considering they've obviously had to include it for didactic purposes"

Does anyone recall such a word? I am fairly sure I am not imagining it...

Comment: There is "*mis-en-scène*" but that doesn't quite match what you ask.

Comment: Are you looking for _diegetic_? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diegetic?wprov=sfti1

Comment: @KarlG Yes, that's the one! Thank you. I will accept if you can put it as an answer? Now I read the definition again my emphasis on the physical could be misleading. What is best practice on this site - is it preferred I alter the question or leave as is?

Comment: As you wish. Frankly, the big cue was that you couldn't remember the word. I don't know how many times I've had to retrace my steps to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often used to describe film music, [*diegetic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diegetic?wprov=sfti1) is part of the film's narrative world that the characters experience as well.  *Extra-diegetic* music is heard only by the audience. A common technique is to begin with diegetic music — say, a single unaccompanied voice — and transition to extra-diegetic, where out of nowhere there is an orchestra and full chorus.

The word in this sense is a recent coinage from the classical concept of *diegesis*. While *mimesis* shows action, *diegesis* narrates it.

Comment: I'll delete my comment (and this one) for tidiness sake :)  Nice word btw.

Answer (score 0):

I find "**unobtrusive**" works in those situations - where something is passively hiding-in-plain-sight.

An active attempt not to be seen, say a spy hiding behind a newspaper, would be "**inconspicuous**".